# setAllowedFileTypes while NSOpenPanel is displayed

Tags: cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have an `NSOpenPanel` with an accessory view. The accessory view is simple - it's a single checkbox that when checked, allows the user to select any file; when un-checked, requires the file to be one in the list of supported extensions.

`NSOpenPanel` initialization and display:

```
NSOpenPanel* dialog = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[dialog setAllowedFileTypes:allowedFileTypes];
[dialog setAccessoryView:openPanelAccessoryView];

openPanel = dialog;

[dialog beginSheetModalForWindow:[self activeWindow]
               completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
 {
     ...
 }];
```

`IBAction` for the checkbox:

```
- (void)openUnrecognizedFiles:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender state])
        [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:nil];
    else
        [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"dsk"]];
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/setAllowedFileTypes%3a), one can use `setAllowedFileTypes` while the panel is displayed:

> The allowed file types can be changed while the panel is running (for
>   example, from an accessory view).

However, this does not seem work as expected: the current view does not reload - as you scroll, files further down *do* get enabled/disabled as appropriate for the new settings; however, files originally visible are unaffected.

I need some way to refresh the contents of the current directory when the user toggles the accessory view checkbox - however, I can't seem to find any way to do it. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**, Oct. 15, 2013: This seems to be caused by a bug in Mavericks more than anything else. Same code running on Mountain Lion works without any issues, just like the two commenters here noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried like this and it worked:

```
NSOpenPanel* dialog = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [dialog setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"png"]];

    NSButton *openPanelAccessoryView = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 324.0, 22.0)] autorelease];

    [openPanelAccessoryView setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];

    [openPanelAccessoryView setBezelStyle:0];

    [openPanelAccessoryView setAction:@selector(openUnrecognizedFiles:)];

    [openPanelAccessoryView setTarget:self];

    [dialog setAccessoryView:openPanelAccessoryView];

     openPanel = dialog;

    [dialog beginSheetModalForWindow:[[self view] window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if(result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
        {

        }
    } ];
```

This is action same as yours:

```
- (void)openUnrecognizedFiles:(id)sender

{
     if ([sender state])
      [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:nil];
     else
      [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"jpeg"]];
}
```

Now file type is changing as per check box on & off.

Comment: File type changes in my case as well. Do files become enabled/disabled when you check/uncheck the box? That's the problem - the view doesn't update when I toggle the checkbox.

Comment: On second thought never mind - what I'm seeing is likely due to a bug in Mavericks GM (see edit to my question).

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide files using `setAllowedFileTypes:` method.  This method will only enable/disable files in open panel.

From `NSSavePanel.h`

> This property will determine which files should be enabled in the open
>   panel

Comment: I'm not interested in hiding the files; I'm interested in enabling/disabling them.

Comment: (s)he wants to enable/disable files while the panel is being shown. When the panel is presented, setting allowedFileTypes has no direct apparent effect. The tableview has to reload its data. So no, it's not working. It only works when you set the allowedFileTypes before presenting the panel.